# php - how do I use a form to display data with multiple where conditions?

Tags: where-clause, conditional-statements

I created a database for a volunteers list.  Then a form to pull out the personal info for volunteers who signed up to volunteer for particular tasks.  I'm a beginner with php, and I have looked all over for an answer and tried multiple ways of doing it, but alas, no luck.

Here is the critical code I am currently struggling with:

```
if(isset($_POST['planning']) && $_POST['planning'] == '1')
  { $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE planning = '1'");}
if(isset($_POST['signatures']) && $_POST['signatures'] == '1')                 
  { $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE signatures = '1'"); 
  $newresult1 = array_merge($result1, $result2);}
if(isset($_POST['canvassing']) && $_POST['canvassing'] == '1')
  { $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE canvassing = '1'");
  $newresult2 = array_merge($newresult1, $result3);}
if(isset($_POST['phone_bank']) && $_POST['phone_bank'] == '1')
  { $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE phone_bank = '1'"); 
  $newresult3 = array_merge($newresult2, $result4);}
if(isset($_POST['media']) && $_POST['media'] == '1')
  { $result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE media = '1'"); $newresult4 =  
  array_merge($newresult3, $result5);}
if(isset($_POST['press_releases']) && $_POST['press_releases'] == '1')
  { $result6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE press_releases = '1'"); 
  $newresult5 = array_merge($newresult4, $result6);}
if(isset($_POST['volunteer_coordinator']) && $_POST['volunteer_coordinator'] == '1')
  { $result7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE volunteer_coordinator =
  '1'"); 
  $newresult6 = array_merge($newresult5, $result7);}
if(isset($_POST['speaker']) && $_POST['speaker'] == '1')
  { $result8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE speaker = '1'"); $newresult7
  = array_merge($newresult6, $result8);}
if(isset($_POST['house_parties']) && $_POST['house_parties'] == '1')
  { $result9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE house_parties = '1'"); 
  $newresult8 = array_merge($newresult7, $result9);}
if(isset($_POST['web_page']) && $_POST['web_page'] == '1')
  { $result10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE web_page = '1'"); 
  $newresult9 
  = array_merge($newresult8, $result10);}
if(isset($_POST['other']) && $_POST['other'] == '1')
  { $result11 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE other = '1'"); $newresult10 
  = array_merge($newresult9, $result11);}

$newresult10 = array_unique($newresult10); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($newresult10)) {
echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];  
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo $row['email'];  
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo $row['phone']; 
echo "<br />";
```

I much appreciated any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it so that it's more like this

**[EDIT]-------- I think this is what your looking for**

```
$postVars = array(
    "canvassing"=>"1",
    "other"=>"1"
    //and you would go on post name valid post value
);

//start the query
$query="SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE ";    

//loop thru the posibable post vars and check and add to the query
$andcount=0;
foreach($postVars as $name=>$value){
    if(isset($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name] == $value){
        if($andcount>0)$query.=" AND ";
        $query.=" ".$name."= '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
        $andcount++;
    }
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];  
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['email'];  
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['phone']; 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got an error message: – HTTP error 500 (internal server error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill thee request.  So I added ";" to the end of each if statement and got past the error message but still come up with a blank page, when I should have gotten two results (2 rows returned).

Comment: Is it a list of post vars that will not change? Cause I think the best way may be to have an array of the post var names and then loop of that.  If so I'll edit the code and that should help make this even easier and cleaner

Comment: I think so. Purpose of the form: Provide a way an organizer can pull list of volunteers who have indicated through another form previously filled out areas/tasks they are interested in volunteering for.  So the organizer has a list of all people that volunteered for canvassing and can send them all an email using PHPMailer, which of course I am also having trouble setting up, but that's another story.  I want the organizer to be able to search for more than one area/skill at one time - canvassing and gathering signatures or media and press releases and speaking to organizations or whatever.

Comment: reposted but may i suggest you lok as a cms app as there are many that would let you do all this function and get you running in a few hours.  Something to think about.

Comment: Which ones would you recommend?

Comment: I'm a major contributor to CMS MadeSimple myself and after doing dev work for all the major ones, thou CMSMS does lacks in areas it's potential to be anything I want it to be is why I use it.  Many will say wordpress but IMNHO it's a blog, let it be that :D, some will say drupal or .. but I just go back everytime.